# Pytorch: CUDA error: invalid configuration argument

Tags: python, pytorch

I am attempting to run some third-party Pytorch code, and am seeing the following error:

```
 File "D:\Testing\OFFLINE\PSFM\particle-sfm\motion_seg\core\network\traj_oa_depth.py", line 48, in extract_feature
    output_feat = self.transformer_model(input_traj, input_traj, \
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 146, in forward
    output = self.decoder(tgt, memory, tgt_mask=tgt_mask, memory_mask=memory_mask,
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 369, in forward
    output = mod(output, memory, tgt_mask=tgt_mask,
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 717, in forward
    x = self.norm2(x + self._mha_block(x, memory, memory_mask, memory_key_padding_mask, memory_is_causal))
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\transformer.py", line 735, in _mha_block
    x = self.multihead_attn(x, mem, mem,
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\activation.py", line 1205, in forward
    attn_output, attn_output_weights = F.multi_head_attention_forward(
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 5373, in multi_head_attention_forward
    attn_output = scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, attn_mask, dropout_p, is_causal)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid configuration argument
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

With the notable line being   `RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid configuration argument`

Google throws up a few [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125389/invalid-configuration-argument-error-for-the-call-of-cuda-kernel), and it seems related to the blocks sent to the GPU, or using an older Pytorch version. My version is `2.0.1+cu117'`

My question is, how can I debug this in code that I did not write? What should I be searching for to find the offending line of Python that sets the GPU blocks?

The function that results in the error is here:

https://github.com/bytedance/particle-sfm/blob/main/motion_seg/core/network/traj_oa_depth.py

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by adding:

```
torch.backends.cuda.enable_mem_efficient_sdp(False)
torch.backends.cuda.enable_flash_sdp(False)
torch.backends.cuda.enable_math_sdp(True)
```

to the python code.

As [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention.html) this uses the Pytorch attenuation approach, and skips the custom CUDA kernels that are causing this error